# How to add 0 to right of decimal for exported numbers

Tags: export, number-representation

I'm using Mathematica to process some grades which are saved via `Export[]`.  However, if I have real versions of integers, the exported numbers don't have a trailing 0. This lack of a trailing 0 messes up the program I am importing the csv file into. Ugh.

```
   Export[ "test.csv", {1.0, 0.0}]
```

You'll see that the output is

```
   1.
   0.
```

Can anyone give me an easy fix for this?  The data I'm exporting is a mixture of strings (some of which are already in double quotes) and numbers.

Comment: `Export["test.csv", NumberForm[{{1., 2.}}, {3, 1}]]`

Comment: Removed the Bugs tag, since this behaviour is expected; it's how Mathematica outputs floating-point numbers which happen to be integer.

Comment: "bugs" might apply to the program that needs trailing zeros to read it !!

Comment: I agree with @george2079 but I would also argue it also applies to mathematica.  The numbers in the example above are not integers.

Comment: @george2079 this output is not correct.  I don't want any brackets in my output.

Comment: @mikemtnbikes No, they're not integers. That's why they have decimal points after them. Mathematica represents integers without decimal points.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/30771/patrick-stevens Now you're confusing me. You said that "it's how Mathematica outputs floating-point numbers which happen to be integers."  As I said, the numbers I used in my example, are not integers.  They are floating points, not integers parading as floating points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forgot we need to do a string conversion as well:

```
 Export["test.csv", 
     Map[ToString[NumberForm[#, {20, 1}]] &, #, {-1}]] &@{{1., 2.}, {3, 4}}

 FilePrint["test.csv"]
```

> [image]

note that this also rounds to a single decimal place. Additionally this breaks when mathematica wants to use scientific notation for large numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I think this is an area where Mathematica is really bothersome.  One should be able to output numbers in a sane manner without having two write extensive code.

Comment: The `ToString[]` can be omitted: `ExportString[Map[NumberForm[#, {20, 1}] &, {{1., 2.}, {3, 4}}, {-1}], "CSV"]`